# PHP CSV check value in column and loop based if value is the same

Tags: php, arrays, json, csv, foreach

I am struggling to figure out the best way to get this to work.

I have a big CSV file that is output from a very old system. I am wanting to output a json file. The CSV has a few columns in it. The 'series' column (col 2) is a unique identifier. and 'part #' is associated to that 'series' code.

**QUESTION:**
What would be the best approach to check if 'series' is the same, then loop through all matches and push the results to the 'pricing' array?

#### I need my json file to output as follows (small example):

```
[
{
    "series": "01000",
    "pricing": [{
        "part_no": "010000.3",
        "size": "0.30mm",
        "stock": "5213",
        "price2020": "4.55",
        "price2017": "3.90",
        "price2018": "0.65"
    },
    {
        "part_no": "010000.35",
        "size": "0.35mm",
        "stock": "36225",
        "price2020": "4.55",
        "price2017": "3.90",
        "price2018": "0.65"
    },
    {
        "part_no": "010000.164",
        "size": "1/64in",
        "stock": "36225",
        "price2020": "4.55",
        "price2017": "3.90",
        "price2018": "0.65"
    }]
},
{
    "series": "01001",
    "pricing": [{
        "part_no": "010001.3",
        "size": "0.30mm",
        "stock": "5213",
        "price2020": "4.55",
        "price2017": "3.90",
        "price2018": "0.65"
    },
    {
        "part_no": "010001.35",
        "size": "0.35mm",
        "stock": "36225",
        "price2020": "4.55",
        "price2017": "3.90",
        "price2018": "0.65"
    },
    {
        "part_no": "010001.164",
        "size": "1/64in",
        "stock": "36225",
        "price2020": "4.55",
        "price2017": "3.90",
        "price2018": "0.65"
    }]
}
]
```

#### The CSV is formatted like this (small example):

```
"Part #","Series #","price0","price1","price2","price3","Size"    
"010000.35","01000",£4.10,€ 3.32,€ 0.92,,"0.35mm","N",0.0138,
"01000-164","01000",£3.89,€ 2.89,€ 0.81,,"1/64""","N",0.0156,
"010000.4","01001",£3.88,€ 3.18,€ 0.65,,"0.40mm","N",0.0157,
"010000.45","01001",£3.66,€ 2.88,€ 0.81,,"0.45mm","N",0.0177,
"010000.5","01000",£2.93,€ 2.59,€ 0.62,,"0.50mm","N",0.0197,
```

I'm output josn just fine, but I can't figure out the best way to check if 'series' is the same and if it is, loop through all matches and create an array within the array.

#### PHP function

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

// Set your CSV feed
$feed = 'pricelist.csv';

// Arrays we'll use later
$keys = array();
$newArray = array();

// Function to convert CSV into associative array
function csvToArray($file, $delimiter) {
if (($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    $i = 0;
    while (($lineArray = fgetcsv($handle, 4000, $delimiter, '"')) !== FALSE) {

        $part        = $lineArray[0];
        $series      = $lineArray[1];
        $janprice    = $lineArray[2];
        $septprice1  = $lineArray[3];
        $septprice2  = $lineArray[4];
        $size        = $lineArray[5];

        if ($series = $series){
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($lineArray); $j++) {
                $arr[$i][$j] = $lineArray[$j];
            }
            $i++;
        }


    }
    fclose($handle);
}
return $arr;
 }

 // Do it
 $data = csvToArray($feed, ',');

 // Set number of elements (minus 1 because we shift off the first row)
 $count = count($data) - 1;
 //Use first row for names
 $labels = array_shift($data);

 foreach ($labels as $label) {
$keys[] = $label;
 }

 // Add Ids, just in case we want them later
 $keys[] = 'id';

 for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
$data[$i][] = $i;
 }
 // Bring it all together
 for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
$d = array_combine($keys, $data[$j]);
$newArray[$j] = $d;
 }

 // Print it out as JSON
 echo json_encode($newArray);

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function csvToArray($file, $delimiter) {
  if (($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    $arr = array();
    $final = array();
    while (($lineArray = fgetcsv($handle, 4000, $delimiter, '"')) !== FALSE) {

        $part          = $lineArray[0];
        $series    = $lineArray[1];
        $janprice     = $lineArray[2];
        $septprice1   = $lineArray[3];
        $septprice2   = $lineArray[4];
        $size          = $lineArray[5];

        if (!isset($arr[$series]))
        {
          $arr[$series] = array();
        }
        array_push($arr[$series], array("part_no" => $part, "size" => $size, ...));
    }
    foreach($arr as $serie => $data)
    {
      array_push($final, array(
        "series" => $serie,
        "pricing" => $data
      ));
    }
    fclose($handle);
  }
return $final;
}
```

Comment: LEGENDARY!! Thanks Alberto. Worked like a charm. Thank you so much.